# Is it possible to combine different URLs that appear in Google Analytics?

Tags: regex, url, google-analytics

We have some URLs in our site that are recorded by GA differently, I believe this is mostly due to browser type.  The issue is due to some URLs coming from an area of our site, that we cannot change at this point without significant effort, which contain spaces.  With the way different browsers handle the spaces we can get the various formats recorded as separate items:

- \my site area\pages\default.html
- \my+site+area\pages\default.html
- \my%20site%20area\pages\default.html

I thought it might be useful to use a regular expression and try to simplify these.

Has anyone had a similar issue, and have you a resolved this?  Ideally I'd like to track all URLs like above as one URL and right now it shows up in my reports as multiple URLs, which skews some of the tracking we have to do, or creates extra work in being able to combine the URLs that are alike.

Answer (score 2):

To do this, you could create a new profile and then create and apply some [search and replace filters](http://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034834?hl=en) to handle re-writing the URLs.

In the example you have above, you could have your search string be:

```
\/my(\s|\+|%20)site(\s|\+|%20)area\/pages\/default\.html
```

And then your replace string could then be whatever format you choose, like this for example:

```
\/my site area\/pages\/default\.html
```

That would map any of the three formats to "/my site area/pages/default.html"

Comment: Thank you, I will check that out.  I had come up with something similar, guess I was not too far off.  I was hoping I could come up with a general regex for this, for any URL that comes in, but after looking at this more I just don't think that will be possible